# Can't Play Video through videoview error

Tags: android-videoview

I tried almost everything but was unable to play the video....I copied the video in my phone...it works well..but the app shows the error "Can't Play this Video"..Please Help me..Here is my code..

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button button;
        private VideoView videoView3;
        private MediaController mc;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view)
                {
                    String path ="android.resource://"+"/"+ R.raw.video;
                    videoView3 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView3);
                    videoView3.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
                    videoView3.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            MediaController mc = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
                            videoView3.setMediaController(mc);
                            mc.setAnchorView(view);
                            videoView3.requestFocus();
                            videoView3.start();

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: add error stack trace please

Comment: There is no error shown in the Android Studio.....the error shows during runtime...